# How to keep Content inside Image Map Area

Tags: image, html, dictionary

So here's what I'm working with: http://shaneboland.com/ms2/contact.html
but this is what I want: http://shaneboland.com/ms2/test.jpg

I have one div that contains my form:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content-pad">
        <div id="mid-col-wide">
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact/send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">Full Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="full_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Message *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div><!-- //mid-col -->

    </div><!-- //content-pad -->

</div><!-- //wrapper -->
```

and then I have a separate div that contains an image map with multiple links:

```
<div align="center">
<img name="emp" src="contact/main.jpg" usemap="#ep" alt="Mammal Swag" width="940" height="801" border="0"/>
<map name="ep">
<area shape="poly" coords="20,144,176,159,183,222,42,223,20,144" href="about.html" onMouseOver="changeabout()" onMouseOut="changemain()"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="49,228,184,228,192,289,118,315,36,265,49,228" href="index.html" onMouseOver="changecontact()" onMouseOut="changemain()"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="675,639,692,607,773,607,754,713,693,712,675,639" href="http://www.facebook.com/MammalSwag" onMouseOver="changefacebook()" onMouseOut="changemain()"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="185,159,370,149,320,243,199,285,185,159" href="index.html" onMouseOver="changehome()" onMouseOut="changemain()"/>
<area shape="poly" coords="821,536,877,626,766,694,779,606,821,536" href="http://www.twitter.com/MammalSwag" onMouseOver="changetwitter()" onMouseOut="changemain()"/>  
</map>
</div>
```

I want to make it so that my contact form div, stays positioned inside that big green space. So when the window is resized, the contact form div, is still in the same spot INSIDE of the green space.

How do I make my contact form div resize with my image map?

Comment: I'd do something about the hot spots of your image map before I started worrying about the positioning of those fields.

Comment: The hotspots on the image work fine. The second link is just a .jpg mockup I made to show what I need done.

Comment: Oh, you solved it. OK...

Comment: Anyway, what you need to do is put the form in the same container as the img (i.e. both in the `div align="center">` that the img is in). That way, they won't move independently of each other. Your page itself is a bit complicated, but I made a simpler example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jYgkq/3/ It has problems in that it doesn't look the same on all browsers, but I hope you can work with it.